# Simulate a submit button click via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to Submit a form with JAVASCRIPT? if yes please help me...

I have a form with input fileds in it. So I want javascript to count if all fields are field in and then press on the submit button.

The submit button "Save" will be hidden from visitors eyes.

```
<form id="my form" action="">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" value=""/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""/>
    <button type="submit" name="submitAccount" id="submitAccount">save</button>
</form>
```

here is a opened [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xb83c/)

Thanks to all for any help!

Comment: There's the jquery trigger function..

Comment: @gratz jQuery is way too bloated for something simple like this

Comment: @RUJordan I assumed he was to be using jquery as it was included in the tags..

Comment: @gratz maybe so, but when `formElement.submit()` exists, what's the point in using a library?

Comment: Because if using jquery elsewhere, mixing ways of element selection is messy..trigger and submit in jquery have shared behavior - agreed if not using jquery though that it is additional bloat

Answer (score 5):

you can submit form via JavaScript even without submit button, `form` element has method `.submit()` which submits whole form.

```
var myForm = document.getElementById('myform');
myForm.submit();
```

Before submiting form you can get values from every field in form and make you own validation.

P.S. don't use values for `id` attribute with whitespace, you should rename it to 'myform' or 'myForm'.

Comment: "So I want javascript to count if all fields are field in and then press on the submit button."

Answer (score 0):

There is  a [`required`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML5_form_additions#required) attribute

```
<form id="myForm" action="">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" required/>
    <input type="text" name="sname" id="sname" value="" required/>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" required/>
    <button type="button" name="submitAccount" id="submitAccount" onclick="checkForm();">save</button>
</form>
```

Form gets submitted only if the required fields are filled